# Camel Bindy Date format Unmarshalling issue

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

I ran into an issue with Apache Camel Bindy data format for the Date field parsing from a CSV file.

Date in the CSV is **`02/11/2015 03:34:49 PM`**

Format in the Bindy Class annotated as

```
@DataField(pos = 8,pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a")
private Date time;
```

Getting below exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Date provided does not fit the
>   pattern defined, position: 8, line: 1     at
>   org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.BindyCsvFactory.bind(BindyCsvFactory.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat.unmarshal(BindyCsvDataFormat.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:67)

It works if the date in the CSV is given as **`2/11/2015 03:34:49 PM`**, with no preceeding 0 in the Month field.

I am using Camel 2.14.1.

Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

From the source code of [DatePatternFormat.java](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.14.1/components/camel-bindy/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/dataformat/bindy/format/DatePatternFormat.java) :

```
public Date parse(String string) throws Exception {

    Date date;
    DateFormat df = this.getDateFormat();

    ObjectHelper.notNull(this.pattern, "pattern");

    // Check length of the string with date pattern
    // To avoid to parse a string date : 20090901-10:32:30 when
    // the pattern is yyyyMMdd

    if (string.length() <= this.pattern.length()) {

        // Force the parser to be strict in the syntax of the date to be
        // converted
        df.setLenient(false);
        date = df.parse(string);

        return date;

    } else {
        throw new FormatException("Date provided does not fit the pattern defined");
    }
}
```

It check that parsed string is smaller than the pattern.

Then changing your pattern to `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa` should fix your problem.